# É possível, numa função, retornar a referência para um índice de um array?

Tags: php, funções, return, referência

A ideia é ter uma função que receba um *array* e retornar a referência para um  índice do mesmo, por exemplo:

```
$list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

function ref(&list) {
    return &$list[3] ?? false;
}
```

A utilização seria em uma função recursiva para buscar um valor em seus elementos, para alterar (ou não):

```
$list = [
    'a' => ['b', 'c'],
    'd' => ['e', 'f' => [
        'g' => ['h', 'i']
    ]],
]
```

A partir desse *array* eu gostaria de encontrar o índice `g`, então a função deve retornar a referência para esse elemento ou falso caso não encontrar. Com o retorno da função posso manipular esse *array*, adicionando, alterando ou excluindo itens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é possível, tem que dizer no nome da função que ela é por referência, tanto na sua declaração quanto na chamada:

```
function &ref(&$list) {
    $return = &$list[3] ?? false;
    return $return;
}
$list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
$elemento = &ref($list);
$elemento = 'D';
echo $list[3]; // D
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/2U7lvo). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/erizcxnf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/RefReturn.php).

Eu tentaria fazer de outra forma, a maioria das pessoas não entende as consequência de ter algo por referência, e quase sempre tem maneiras melhores de resolver o mesmo problema. Uma das grandes vantagens é de performance, mas é o que eu sempre falo, se precisa de performance PHP não é a linguagem adequada.